# VBA GET request failing, bad format?

Tags: vba, excel, get

I'm a novice and your help has been amazing so far!  I have an issue with a GET request for SSO authentication in an Excel Visual Basic script.  The API says to send the GET request to:

https://services.example.com/API/Security.svc/SSOSiteLogin/siteId/enterpriseGuid/authToken/timezoneOffset

Where the values for siteID, enterpriseGUID, authToken, and timezoneOffset have all been obtained by previous GET requests, which have worked fine.  When I send the final GET request for a security token, it returns:

{"Detail":"SSOSiteLogin failed.Input string was not in a correct format."}

Here is my relevant code:

```
Dim hreq As New WinHttpRequest
Dim response As String
Dim URL As String
    'get security token
URL = "https://services.example.com/API/Security.svc/SSOSiteLogin/siteID/enterpriseGUID/" & authToken & "/null"
hreq.Open "GET", URL, False
hreq.Send

response = hreq.ResponseText
Range("A13") = response
```

The siteID and enterpriseGUID variables are input into the code, and the authToken is stored from an earlier POST request.  The last value, timezoneOffset, is given as "null" from an earlier request so I've been typing "/null" at the end but I'm concerned that's what's triggering the incorrect format response.  Anything else just returns a total error from the server though.

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: You definitely don't want the literal string "null". I would first try leaving it as a trailing slash ... Nothing else

Comment: Edit timeout. Leave trailing slash. If that fails remove trailing slash. Also you should recheck your call to get timezone offset. That sounds suspect that it returns null

Comment: By trailing slash do you mean just ending it as "//"?  I've tried that, "/", "/" & Null, and none of them work.  They just return an error from the schema saying an improper method was used.  Only adding text after the "/" returns the error I posted above.  I thought the null response earlier was odd, but it comes from the same POST that gives the authToken, and in the API guide the example says "timezoneOffset:"null" too.  It's just strange.

Answer (score 0):

I had put the values into cells and was sending the GET request as `"Range("E5") & "/" & Range("E6") & "/",` etc. so that I could try a couple of debugging issues without having to go to the VBA editor and for some reason that worked!  I ended up using the string "null", too.  If anyone knows why this worked and inputting it all as one string doesn't I'd be interested to find out.